# naming the file in c++

Tags: c++, file

when i run this code the 2nd & 3rd files' names the first character disappear
for example if i named the 2nd file set2.txt it will be et2.txt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

        fstream set1,set2,set3;
        string name;
        cout<<"Enter set1 name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin , name);
        set1.open(name,ios::out);
        cout<<"Enter set2 name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin , name);
        set2.open(name,ios::out);
        cout<<"Enter set3 name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin , name);
        set3.open(name,ios::out); 
    }
```

Comment: Plese read what `debugger` is, how to activate it and how to use in your IDE to step walk your code.

Comment: Perfect time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski How will a debugger help here? It is nearly impossible to see what input is available from stdin without actually reading it...which the OP is already doing.

Comment: Sure it will, You will be able to see what each variable holds at every step of your code.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The OP clearly knows the contents of the variables in question but doesn't understand why they have those contents. To figure this out with a debugger would require inspecting the contents of the variable named `cin` which isn't exactly helpful for a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

> the first character disappear

That is because you ignore the first character with the line

```
cin.ignore();
```

before you read the a line of text with

```
getline(cin , name);
```

These two lines are in the wrong order. Instead they should be

```
getline(cin , name);
cin.ignore();
```

The purpose of `cin.ignore()` here is to remove the newline character from the input stream **after** you read a line of text with `getline()`.

Comment: Actually, you only need `cin.ignore()` on files with DOS line-endings, as these consist of two characters. `getline()` will read and discard the newline character that terminates the input line, but only a single one. Thus, on DOS you need extra code to discard the extra character, on UNIX, you don't.